# Unable create MQ session from WAS7

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I'm facing a problem while create MQ operation with WAS 7.0.0.35(64 bit) in Linux environment.

**System configuration**-

WAS version :- 7.0.0.35(64 bit)
OS - Redhat Enterprise Linux 5.8 x86_64
WebSphere MQ:-7.5

Note:- MQ and WAS server are installed in different machine. Transport type TCP is is used for MQ.

**WAS Configuration**:
Classloader policy at server level is:: Single
Class loading mode at server level is :: Classes loaded with parent class loader first.

Classloader policy at application level is:: Classes loaded with parent class loader first.

**MQ Logs we found following error**-

Process(8240.4) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
Host(mq-qa1.XXXfintech.com) Installation(Installation1)
VRMF(7.5.0.0) QMgr(krishnendur.LLLmv.XXXfintech.com)

**AMQ9504**: A protocol error was detected for channel 'CHKMV'.

EXPLANATION:
During communications with the remote queue manager, the channel program
detected a protocol error. The failure type was 11 with associated data of 0.
ACTION:
Contact the systems administrator who should examine the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure.

**Errors in Application logs**-

[2015-08-19 13:43:37,835]-[WARN ]-[bContainer : 10]-[com.abc.AspectFailOver.ajc$before$com_XXX__AspectFailOver$3$73ca82ff(){82}]-Generic Exception
**javax.jms.JMSException: CC=2;RC=2009**

```
    at com.abc.inf.QueueConnectionFactoryBean.createQueueConnection(QueueConnectionFactoryBean.java:159)
    at com.abc.inf.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.newSession(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:67)
    at com.abc.inf.QueueHandler.<init>(QueueHandler.java:115)
    at com.abc.inf.QueueHandlerFactory.getHandler(QueueHandlerFactory.java:51)
    at com.abc.ref.web.base.AbstractWizardController.commitAction(AbstractWizardController.java:1055)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1635)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
    ....
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)

[2015-08-19 13:43:37,837]-[ERROR]-[bContainer : 10]-[applicationclass.QueueXXX.<init>(){118}]-javax.jms.JMSException: CC=2;RC=2009
[2015-08-19 13:43:37,837]-[WARN ]-[bContainer : 10]-[applicationclass.AFOXXX.ajc$before$cxxxxxxx(){82}]-Generic Exception
applicationclass.MKEClass: **Failed To Create MQ Session**
    at applicationclass.QueueXXX.<init>(QueueXXX.java:119)
    at applicationclass.QueueXXXZZZ.getHandler(QueueXXXZZZ.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1635)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
    ....
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
```

**But in WAS logs we found following Error code**-

1. Error code related to MQbind
   ** mqjbnd level     :-  CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568**

   Messaging Provider Components:
   |   CMVC             :-  k700-L080820

   |   Class Name       :-  class com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQComponent

   |   Component Name   :-  com.ibm.msg.client.wmq

   |   Component Title  :-  IBM WebSphere MQ

   |   Factory Class    :-  class com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory

   |   Version          :-  7.0.0.0

   |  mqjbnd level     :-  CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd' was not found. [3=mqjbnd]::mqjbnd (Not found in java.library.path)

   Provider Specific Information

   ---

   Overview of JMS System
   Num. Connections : 1
   Num. Sessions    : 0
   Num. Consumers   : 0
   Num. Producers   : 0

   .....
   |   queueManagerName            :-  XXXst2.XXXmv.AAAfintech.com

   |   XMSC_CONNECTION_TYPE              :-  1

   |   XMSC_CONNECTION_TYPE_NAME         :-  com.ibm.msg.client.wmq
2. Another error code found in logs is
   **com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteHconn Reason Code:2009 and compcode:2**

   ```
                            FFDC
   ```

   Exception:com.ibm.ws.wmqcsi.trace.WMQClientException SourceId: ProbeId:XN00100C Reporter:java.util.HashMap@24252425
   com.ibm.ws.wmqcsi.trace.WMQClientException:

   ```
                                   FDCTitle
   ```

   Source Class     :- com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection

   Source Method    :-

   ProbeID          :- XN00100C

   Thread           :- name=WebContainer : 10 priority=5 group=main ccl=
   com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@11621162[war:XXXmv-LLL-qa/YYY-tomcat.war]

   ...
   Parent: com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@f120f12[app:XXXmv-LLL-qa]

   Delegation Mode: PARENT_FIRST

   ```
                                     Data
                                     ----
   ```

   |   **compcode  :-  2**
   |   hconn     :-  com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteHconn[connectionId=414D51436E696E7374322E6E696E6D76E4C1905501054F20]
   |   **reason    :-  2009**

   ```
                             Version information
                             -------------------
   ```

   WebSphere MQ classes for Java Message Service
   7.0.0.0
   k700-L080820
   Production

   Java Message Service Client
   7.0.0.0
   k700-L080820
   Production

   IBM WebSphere MQ
   7.0.0.0
   k700-L080820
   Production

   Common Services for Java Platform, Standard Edition
   1.0.0.0
   k700-L080820
   Production

   null
   null
   Production

   ```
                                 Stack trace
                                 -----------
   ```

   Stack trace to show the location of the FFST call
   |   FFST Location  :-  java.lang.Exception
   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.getCurrentPosition(Trace.java:1671)
   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.createFFSTString(Trace.java:1610)
   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffstInternal(Trace.java:1494)
   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffst(Trace.java:1353)
   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.(WMQConnection.java:438)
   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7855)
   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7331)
   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:276)
   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6058)
   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:144)
   |       at com.abc.inf.AAAQueueConnectionFactoryBean.makeObject(AAAQueueConnectionFactoryBean.java:221)

Thanks & Regards,

Krishnendu

Comment: Are you sure your connection factory is not configured to Bindings mode? Check this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21413508) maybe it will provide some info. Do you have qcf configured in WebSphere?

Comment: From the information you have provided, it appears that you are using the WebSphere MQ v7.0.0.0 Resource Adapter (probably without realising). I would start by following this guide in the KC to ensure you are using the latest available WMQ RA for your WSAS version: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tmj_wmqra_restoredefault.html

Comment: @ Gas,  Are you sure your connection factory is not configured to Bindings mode?  
Today I have checked again TCP (com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP) is  used as transport type.

Comment: @ Gas, Check this link maybe it will provide some info.  
We have already try that but faced same problem.

Comment: @ Gas, Do you have qcf configured in WebSphere?  
No.

Comment: Today I got one more information in MQ logs- AMQ9504: A protocol error was detected for channel. I have update the description part.

Comment: You should configure connection factory in WebSphere, not creating it manually in the code. I hope you are not bundling mq jars with your application, are you? And as `a_cornish_pasty` suggested - update your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue is IBM MQ APAR "[IV36766: MQ V7.0.0.0 JAVA CLIENT APPLICATION CONNECTING TO MQ V7.1 QMGR GETS AMQ9504 PROTOCOL ERROR; FDC HAS PROBE IDS RM680037 RM039000](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV36766)"

> **Problem summary**
>
> ---
>
> USERS AFFECTED:
>
> Users of v7.0.0.0 Java clients connecting to a v7.1 or v7.5
>   queue manager may be affected by this problem.
>
> Platforms affected:
>
> All Distributed (iSeries, all Unix and Windows)
>
> ---
>
> PROBLEM SUMMARY:
>
> A bug existed in the v7.0.0.0 JMS client flow which
>   was fixed in later versions of the code. On queue managers earlier
>   than v7.1, the invalid flow was not detected.
>
> Code was added in v7.1 to detect and report the invalid flow and this
>   detection resulted in the rrcE_PROTOCOL_ERROR FDCs being produced.
>
> **Problem conclusion**
>
> It is correct behavior for the queue manager to
>   report the invalid flow so this code change was not reverted.
>
> The recommended solution for the problem is to upgrade any client
>   still at v7.0.0.0 to a later releae, as Client releases at v7.0.1.0 or
>   later contain a fix for the client code so that it does not send an
>   invalid flow to the queue manager.

Also to note that MQ v7.0 is end of service as of September 30th 2015, but if included in a supported WAS version will remain supported until the WAS version is EOS.